# How to set custom component template and pass template arguments?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to create a custom component with some custom template. And I want this template to have some arguments. Now my code looks like so:

```
    Ext.define('Ext.ux.TestComponent', {
        extend:'Ext.Component',
        alias: 'widget.testcomponent', 
        requires: [
            'Ext.XTemplate'
        ],
        constructor: function(config) {
            Ext.applyIf(config, {
                tpl: [
                    '<div class="custom_cls" custom_attr="{custom_attr_value}">Hello world</div>',
                    {compiled: true}
                ]
            });
            this.callParent([config]);
        }
    });

    Ext.create("Ext.ux.TestComponent",{
        renderTo: document.getElementById("component")
    });
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/21ea) with this code. The first problem with this code is that my custom template is not rendered at all. The second problem, is that I do not know how to pass arguments to this template (and to set `custom_attr` in my example). When I extend `Button`, for example, I know I can use `renderTpl` and `getTemplateArgs()` and when I extend `DataView`, I can configure the template inside the constructor. But all this just does not work, when I extend `Component`. So, what is wrong with that and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your template within the [`renderTpl`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-renderTpl) configuration.
Additional data can be applied via [`renderData`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-renderData).

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.TestComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    renderTpl: [
        '<div class="custom_cls" custom_attr="{custom_attr_value}">Hello</div>'
    ],
    renderData: {
        custom_attr_value: "TestValue"
    }
});
```

Here is the full example:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/21eg

---

As an alternative to handing over the `renderData` object, you can implement an `initRenderData` function in your component. 
This function is called by the mixin [`Ext.util.Renderable`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.util.Renderable.html), which is used by `Ext.Component`.

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.TestComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    renderTpl: [
        '<div>{title}</div>'
    ],

    config: {
        title: 'default',
    },

    initRenderData() {
        return this;
    },
});

Ext.create("Ext.ux.TestComponent", {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    title: 'TestTitle'
});
```

Here is my full example for this alternative solution:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/21en

Comment: I do not like this `renderData` way of passing arguments. By default you hard code arguments in component definition. And when you create instances of this component, you have to use again this `renderData` property. It is totally different from `getTemplateArgs` way of passing arguments or through passing them in a constructor.

Comment: GetTemplateArgs is not a standard method of ExtJs. Not all classes derived from Ext.Component use this approach.
Behind this concept lies the mixin "Ext.util.Renderable". This calls the "initRenderData" method, if it exists.  
I added another example to my answer. Does this help you more?

Comment: Thank you, sir! The second approach suits me much better!

Answer (score 2):

`tpl` is used in conjunction with the `data` config.

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.TestComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',

    tpl: [
        '<div class="custom_cls" custom_attr="{custom_attr_value}">{content}</div>'
    ]
});

Ext.create("Ext.ux.TestComponent", {
    renderTo: document.body,
    data: {
        custom_attr: 'x',
        content: 'y'
    }
});
```